# How to use getImageData() with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, getimagedata

In order to get pixel data in an JavaScript array I need to use HTML method  getImageData().
To use this method I normally would link *canvas HTML element* with *JavaScript sketch.js* variable:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = c.getContext("2d"); 
var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
```

However, I need to work with code where there is no canvas element in index.html file but instead there is a link from sketch file:

```
canvasContainer = select('#content');
```

to an index.html file:

```
<div id="content"></div>.
```

Does anyone know how to use getImageData() method in this scenario?
Thanks

Comment: "instead there is a link from a sketch file" a link to what?

Comment: I don't quite get why you can't use a canvas, could you use an invisible one? `display:none`

Comment: @chiliNUT there is a link from sketch.js file to an index.html file. canvasContainer = select('#content');  <div id="content"></div>

Comment: @Other Me In order to use canvas with getImageData() method I need to have a canvas element in index.html file. As I don't have it, I am trying to find out how to use that method.

Comment: So is there a canvas in the div? if so you could access it through `canvasContainer.children[0]` I personally haven't used sketch.js but isn't there a canvas somewhere?

Comment: @OtherMe I have a canvas in sketch file. So you are proposing .children. I haven't tried that.